# Celery tasks for different python app in different Docker containers

Tags: python, docker, redis, celery, resque

I have reading official Celery's [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/), DigitalOcean's [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-celery-with-rabbitmq-to-queue-tasks-on-an-ubuntu-vps) and run that pretty nice [examples](https://github.com/RichardBronosky/celery_test/). But I can't understand how my apps can communicate like in Resque Ruby. For example, I have main python app in docker container that must generate the task for 2 other python apps in other containers. In Resque my apps just listening some queues and takes the tasks, then do some jobs and push back response.

Answer (score 0):

Celery also needs a queue / broker to to communicate between application processes and worker processes. See http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/index.html for supported brokers (RabbitMQ is often used for that).

The application process posts a new task to a queue on the broker and a worker will fetch it from the queue as soon as the worker has available capacity.

You say you need to pass tasks to two other python apps. These python apps could be made to listen to two different queues and work on them.

Comment: So, can you explain how can I send tasks to other apps? Would be better if give me example of code.